# How to obtain the ForeignKey id to create a new form linked with the model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, foreign-key-relationship

I am pretty sure that question have been covered but I tried everything I found related on the stack to solve my problem without any success.

Here is my model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Description(models.Model):
    titre_routine = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type_routine = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lieu_routine = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    periode = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    routine_description = models.TextField()
    raison_chgmt = models.TextField(blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #prendre une liste de routine et faire une liste de choix
    #si non ajout a la liste de routine dans nouvelle table

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titre_routine

#User.profile = property(lambda u: Description.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])


class Rewards(models.Model):
    jour = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    activite_altr = models.TextField()
    first_word = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    second_word = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    third_word = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    urge_validator = models.BooleanField() #urge satisfait ou non?
    urge_validate_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    description = models.ForeignKey(Description)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.jour
```

To explain my model:
One "user" can create multiple "description".
a "description" contain multiple "rewards".
...
a "description" contain multiple "other things"

here is my view.py

```
#the user access to his dashboard, dashboard filtered by the user logged in.
@login_required(login_url='/userauth/login/')
def dashboard(request):
    routine_info = Description.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render_to_response('dashboard.html', {
        'routine_info': routine_info
    })

#dashboard for the reward section that should be like the first dashboard filtered only by the user logged in AND should only show the reward related to One description created previously by the user.
@login_required(login_url='/userauth/login/')
def reward_dashboard(request):
    reward_info = Rewards.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('rewards_dashboard.html', {
        'reward_info': reward_info
    })


#the user can have access to the reward he created as the other def, he should be the only one to have access (again reward created by the user and related to ONE description)
@login_required(login_url='/userauth/login/')
def reward_description(request, reward_id):
    reward_info = Rewards.objects.get(id=reward_id)
    return render_to_response('reward_description.html', {
        'reward': reward_info
    })

#rewardform, I miss the pieces to obtain de description id that will link both table Rewards and Description (and recursively the User table via Description???)
@login_required(login_url='/userauth/login/')
def new_reward(request):

    if request.POST:
        form = RewardsForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit= False)
            obj.description = #Missing piece

            #test that could never happen
            if obj.description == 200:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/reward_dashboard/')
            else:
                obj.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/reward_dashboard/')

    else:
        form = RewardsForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('create_reward.html', args)
```

to recapitulate:

-the user can have access to the reward he created as the other def he should be the only one to have access (again reward created by the user and related to ONE description)

-dashboard for the reward section that should be has the first dashboard filtered only by the user logged in AND should only show the reward related One description created previously.

-rewardform, I miss the pieces to obtain de description id that will link both table Rewards and Description (and recursively the User table via Description)

Should I try to look into session? (when a user create a description I assign him a specific Id?)

I just hope I made my case clear in my explanation.

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple choices to solve this. It really depends on the workflow you want to implement in your app.

## Choose a description before creating the reward

You will have a page listing all the user's descriptions : this is your dashboard view.
From here, the user will have to choose the description he wants to add a reward to : by clicking on it, by click on a specific **create reward** link, etc. This is up to you (ergo/design choice). The main point is to get the description **id** and pass it to your `new_reward` view via URLconf (`urls.py`) with something like this :

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  # your urlpatterns ...
  url(r'^description/(?P<description_id>\d+)/reward/add/$', 'your.app.views.new_reward', name='add-reward'),
  # your urlpatterns ...
)
```

This is just an example. You can set the URL as you want. Anyway, when your user will click on the link or the button (or whatever you choosed) the URL will be something like **mondomaine.fr/yourappprefix/description/4/reward/add** (where 4 is the id of the chosen description - it will be up to you to generate such a link)

With that, in your view, you can retrieve the description object :

```
#rewardform, I miss the pieces to obtain de description id that will link both table Rewards and Description (and recursively the User table via Description???)
@login_required(login_url='/userauth/login/')
def new_reward(request, description_id):
    description = Description.objects.get_or_404(id=description_id)
    pass
```

## Create a reward with a direct link

If such a workflow is not even an option in your case, then smply add a description field to your `RewardsForm`. With that, your user will be able to aim the description he wants to add a reward to.

To limit the descriptions list to only the ones created by the current user, you could do this in your views.py :

```
# your code ...
else:
    form = RewardsForm()
    form.fields['description'].queryset = Description.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Maybe you will have to do the save if `form.is_valid` returns `False`.

I hope that helps you at least.

Comment: Thank Tony, I kinda make a mix of what you wrote and made me think and now it works great! I will add below my new code

Answer (score 0):

In my models.py
I only added a ForeignKey to link my other table (Rewards to User), to be able to get the current id of the current logged user (to restrict the description that do not belongs to the user)

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

in my urls.py

```
url(r'^reward_dashboard/(?P<routine_id>\d+)/$', reward_dashboard),
url(r'^reward_create/(?P<description_id>\d+)/$', new_reward),
url(r'^reward_description/(?P<reward_id>\d+)/$', reward_description),
```

in my views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='/userauth/login/')
def reward_dashboard(request, routine_id):    (get the routine_id to only get the dashboard related to the description)
    d = Description.objects.get(id=routine_id) #give the object with description related)
    reward_info = Rewards.objects.filter(user=request.user).filter(description=d) #filter with the right description (from the routine_id passed in) and the right user logged.
    return render_to_response('rewards_dashboard.html', {
        'reward_info': reward_info,
        'd' : d      #i will in my template render the d.id in a link {{reward_id}}
    })


@login_required(login_url='/userauth/login/')
def reward_description(request, reward_id):
    reward_info = Rewards.objects.filter(user=request.user).get(id=reward_id)
    return render_to_response('reward_description.html', {
        'reward': reward_info
    })

@login_required(login_url='/userauth/login/')
def new_reward(request, description_id):
    #description = Description.objects.get_or_404(id=description_id)

    d = Description.objects.get(id=description_id) #get all object with the description_id
    if request.POST:
        form = RewardsForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit= False)
            obj.description = d #fill the form with the id that come from my template link
            obj.user = request.user #fill the user with the logged one

            if obj.description == 200:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/')
            else:
                obj.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect("/reward_dashboard/%s" % d.id)

    else:
        form = RewardsForm()



    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form
    args['d'] = d 

    return render_to_response('create_reward.html', args)
```

I hope my explanation would help.

ps: I will take a look to the get_or_404() to understand how it work because for now i don't  see now the difference in result but for sure would be interesting to redirect the user who try to have access he do not belong.